# Pretty Permalink for Search Queries Not Working

Tags: permalinks, search, rewrite-rules

As the title suggests I am trying to create pretty permalinks for search queries, but unfortunately I cant get them to work.

I am trying to achieve the folllowing:

```
website.com/search/something+searched
```

will go to the following

```
website.com/?s=something+searched
```

I have tried the following rewrite rule within the 'init' action.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^/]*)/$','?search=true&s=$matches[1]','top');
```

This doesn't work, although 'website.com/search/something' will go to the search page but not pass the var. As does the below code:

```
 
function search_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'search/(.+)'    =>  'index.php?s='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'search_rewrite' );
```

I believe I'm missing something on my search.php file but I'm not sure what.

Is there a reason for search queries / rewrites to behave differently to other rewrites?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Cheers

Noel

Comment: If you pass the Query to s manually do results get returned w/o the permalinks?

Comment: the search_rewrite function would be in my functions.php file. The add_rewrite_rule was in a must use plugin

Comment: I reformed my comment after you saw it.  Look again...

Comment: Thats correct. If I manually query s the results get returned as normal without returning the permalinks. I am also flushing the permalinks.

Comment: Your question is also [here at the forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-default-search-string-s-to-permalink-structure)

Comment: @ECarterYoung cheers for the heads up. Thats somebody with a similar problem, but alas it doesn't actually help me in my situation. I still have the problem of my rewrites not working. Have looked at the different methods of changing the permalinks but I cant get them to work. Also added the var search=true and it hasn't helped.

Comment: ECarterYoung found the problem, I wasn't using get_query_var('s'). Cheers for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schoolboy error!

I was using:

```
$_GET['s'];
```

as opposed to:

```
get_query_var('s');
```

Hence the empty search results.

Hope this might help somebody in the future!